# Simple way to use mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site has two parts that uses id to unique identify itens. How can i use mod_rewrite to change both URLs when the user click on them?

URL1:
http://www.example.com/category.php?id=1

URL2:
http://www.example.com/article.php?id=1

Would like:

URL1: http://www.example.com/category/1

URL2: http://www.example.com/article/1

With the code below i've achieved what i want but loses the CSS style:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9]+)$ category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Include the "category/" and "article/" parts in your rewrite rules to differentiate them from each other.

Comment: @showdev I already tried it before and did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem i had to add (/) before each path of the link style and js source:

Before:

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After

```
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "/css/style.css">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that result doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)$ category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)$ article.php?id=$1
```

Comment: i tried that before but the problem is that the CSS style disappears

Comment: That's because you probably linked them using a relative path (i.e. "css_folder/something.css" or "../css_folder/something.css") . When you mod_rewrite something like that you also need to consider that you're changing the folder tree. In order to solve that, just use 
    "/css_folder/something.css"
or
    $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]+"/css_folder/something.css"
or anything else you can do to ensure a root-relative path.